# How to count closely connected objects (MJ seeds) in an image when there is minimal background?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, data-analysis

I have an image of MJ Seeds [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh3aL.jpg). The seeds are connected extremely closely, so much so, there is minimal to almost no background.

The approach is to count the centers of the circles. The general idea is you threshold and then flood fill from a background pixel to fill in the background (flood fill works like the paint bucket tool in photo editing apps), that way you only see the centers.

Here is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('seeds copy.jpg', 0)
seed_pt = (25, 25)
fill_color = 0
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
for th in range(60, 120):
    prev_mask = mask.copy()
    mask = cv2.threshold(img, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    mask = cv2.floodFill(mask, None, seed_pt, fill_color)[1]
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask, prev_mask)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

n_centers = cv2.connectedComponents(mask)[0] - 1
print('There are %d cells in the image.'%n_centers)
```

The output is:

```
There are 36 cells in the image.
```

This is a greatly inaccurate. There are way more than 36 seeds in the image. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you look at `mask` you'll see that there are a lot of seeds that are merged so will be counted as one blob. A couple of [erosions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb) on your mask prior to finding the blob centers would probably do the trick.

Comment: You might want to binarize with adaptiveThreshold and run findContours with RETR_CCOMP and filter the hierarchy-2 contours along with their size (min and max). Read about that here https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html